# Parameter in Qliksense

Tags: tableau-api, qliksense

I want to create Parameter based Graph like Tableau.
From the front end the user will provide parameter value  & with respect to that the Variable value will change: 
E.g:

User Input  EUR to INR= X( Stored in X for which 78/79/81/91 etc value will be given by user)

Graph of Company Vs  Sum of Sales in Kilo Euro ( Sales/(X*1000)) will vary accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable and use input box extension, linked to this variable, that allow the user to change the variable content. Changing the variable content will change the expressions result for all expressions where the variable is used

There are few extensions available and one of them comes pre-installed with Qlik sense itself with the Dashboard Bundle.

Please refer to the Qlik's help page how to use it - [Variable input control](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/DashboardBundle/variable-input.htm)